# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'responses' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

```
def chat():
    print("Start talking with the bot (type quit to stop)!")
    while True:
        inp = input("You: ")
        if inp.lower() == "quit":
            break

        results = model.predict([bag_of_words(inp, words)])[0]
        results_index = numpy.argmax(results)
        tag = labels[results_index]
      

        if results[results_index] > 0.7: 
            for tg in data["intents"]:
                if tg['tag'] == tag:
                    responses = tg['responses']
            
            print(random.choice(responses))
        else:
            print("I couldn't get what u meant.")
chat()
```

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UF-NQqg3SbUWdUoh-a3iBXcD1JsWg7y3/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102983311954188847696&rtpof=true&sd=true

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'responses' referenced before assignment

Comment: Please attach the code so that the question can be more clear

Comment: What if `data['intents']` is empty or the `if` condition is never true…?

Comment: The `responses` variable is only defined if *two* previous if statements validate to `True`. Therefore, the second if statement is not validating, so the required variable is not being set. Or, `data` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You declare the `responses` variable in an `if` statement. So if the code execution doesn't enter this scope, this variable will not be assigned. That's why you get an error.

To fix this, assign some 'empty' value to this variable before the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first declare the `responses` outside the if statement so that the scope of it will be in the `while` loop

```
responses = []
if results[results_index] > 0.7: 
     for tg in data["intents"]:
          if tg['tag'] == tag:
               responses = tg['responses']
```